# Rest queries on ProjectOnline should use _API/ProjectData or _API/ProjectServer?

Tags: rest, project-server, api, project-online

I've been trying to identify what is the correct way to get data from Project Online for some time now (I just want to get data, not update it).
I can find documentation on ProjectData and a lot of examples using it. But it requires permission edition on the Project Online configuration.

I Barely can find any example or documentation for the ProjectServer and its
endpoints seem to have fewer options than ProjectData.

Which one should be used to GET info from the ProjectOnline and why?

Doc for ProjectData: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-odata/jj163015(v%3doffice.15)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-odata/jj163015(v%3Doffice.15))

Comment: How can I get all projects which are active
/_api/ProjectData/Projects/ /_api/ProjectServer/Projects/ Where Project Status = active ? How to write this query to read only active projects

Answer (score 0):

It depends what You want to read.
If You want project/task etc. You can easily go with ProjectData.
If You need EnterpriseResources/CustomFields you may need to use ProjectServer.

You can type in a browser http://url/.../ProjectData or http://.../_api/ProjectServer and find out what You can access. ProjectData is formed more friendly way (including custom fields)